# How do I add another subitem in a listview item after its done downloading?

Tags: c#, file, listview, download

I have this application with a listview control and a button.
When I press the button i want it to add the time and the name of the file to a listview and then add it to the control, once its done downloading the file I want it to add another subitem to the same listview but for some reason its not adding it and I cant figure out why, am I calling something wrong?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Listviews
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        WebClient webClient;


        public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
        {
            using (webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);

                try
                {
                    // Start downloading the file
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(urlAddress), location);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        // The event that will trigger when the WebClient is completed
        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Download has been canceled.");
            }
            else
            {
                ListViewItem lvItems = new ListViewItem();
                lvItems.SubItems.Add("Done");
                listView1.Items.Add(lvItems);
            }
        }


        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem lvItems = new ListViewItem();
            string clock = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            lvItems.Text = clock;
            listView1.Items.Add(lvItems);

            string requestUrl = "url";
            string fileName = "\\Name";
            string savePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

            string combinedPaths = savePath + fileName;
            DownloadFile(requestUrl, combinedPaths);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but shouldn't you just put the same code that's inside `btnInstall_Click` into the `else` statement you have in `Completed`? Even better would be to create a method called something like `AddListViewItem` with this code in and then just call the method in both places with `AddListViewItem();`.

Comment: Basically what im trying to do is.. When I press download I want it to add an item to the list with the time as the text, name of what its downloading as the first subitem and once its done downloading it should add the text "Done" as the last subitem.. The issue is that I cant add things to the listview item from Completed event. Do you understand what I mean or should I make it more clear? I tend to explain quite roughly.

Comment: You should probably explain why you can't add a new item from the completed event and exactly what happens when you try. I assume you get an error about accessing a control from another thread which changes this question entirely. I think this question got no attention as it's not clear what you want, add this detail and you may be able to get an answer.

Comment: Add the details to the question, don't put it in comments.

Comment: The basic idea is that in the `Completed` event you need to get a reference to the existing list item and modify it, at the moment you create a new one and add it which is why you get two. You can get a reference by index `listview.Items[index];` or by text `listview.FindItemWithText("text");`. You could pass the relevant information to the completed event using `QueryString` on the webclient. I may write an answer later if I have time, not promising anything.

Comment: This would seriously need to many changes and work to get onto your requirements. You'll face another problems like `identifying the right row` because of a missing key. The ListView itself is also a bit uncomfortable according accessing columns. I would maybe go a slightly different way. If you want, you can join me in here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48058/trash so I can at least give you an idea for the "how-to". Otherwise, hope for someone posting a big answer.