# How come I need to remove the current item in my listview before adding another one?

Tags: c#, listview

So im trying something new..
I added a global ListViewItem at the top of the code so I can easily add new subitems to the list whenever I see it fits.

So to try this new method out I made a simple list view and a button to add the current time.
When I click it once it works great but if i try clicking add again it throws me this error.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot add or insert the item '11:24' in
>   more than one place. You must first remove it from its current
>   location or clone it.'

is there a way I can get past this without removing or cloning it?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Listviews
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            lvi.Text = time;
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't re-use the same `ListViewItem`, making it global like that makes no sense. Move the line `ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();` into the `btnAdd_Click` method, this will create a new item each time which is the desired behaviour.

Comment: I was trying to apply this to my other question that didnt get any attention maybe you would be able to help [My other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069363/how-do-i-add-another-subitem-in-a-listview-item-after-its-done-downloading) *Updated the link*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the same item again and again (a different text don't means it is another item). The `Add` method of `ListView` has an overload that accepts a string. This way a new `listviewitem` will be automatically created.

```
namespace Listviews
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // Not needed
        //ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            // Just add the time directly as a string
            listView1.Items.Add(time);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively check the first comment under your question. But as long as you don't want to modify the items or store them externally, you wouldn't need to create a `listViewItem`.

Comment: That works great and I kept thinking that I could re use it, check my comment above I was trying to apply this to my other question which had the same error message.

Comment: 1. don't mix things up. If it solved what you asked for, mark it and we are done. 2. Your posted link is about asynchronous downloads. Cant see the connection.

Comment: Updated the link.

Comment: Also I cant accept the answer yet forgot to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ListViewItem lvi;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lvi  = new ListViewItem();
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
        lvi.Text = time;
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
```

You can use this .

Comment: This would remove the already existing item from the list view. How does it solve the problem of preserving the earlier added item?

Comment: it's not delete previous item from listview control. It add new item in list